# "Must Declare the Scalar Variable" Migration Error When Running Pipeline in Azure Dev Ops

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, azure-devops

I am trying to create a stored procedure in Entity Framework Core v6.0.13. My migration file looks like the following:

```
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;

#nullable disable

namespace Topology.Infrastructure.Migrations
{
    public partial class StoredProcs : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.Sql(
                @"CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RecordActivity (@activityName NVARCHAR(1024), @pipelineName NVARCHAR(1024)) AS
                INSERT INTO dbo.PipelineActivity (ActivityName, PipelineName) VALUES (@activityName, @pipelineName)");
            migrationBuilder.Sql(
                @"CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RecordActivityRun (@activityName NVARCHAR(1024), @pipelineName NVARCHAR(1024), @context NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS
                INSERT INTO dbo.ActivityRun (ActivityName, PipelineName, Context) VALUES (@activityName, @pipelineName, @context)");
        }
        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.Sql("DROP PROCEDURE dbo.RecordActivity");
            migrationBuilder.Sql("DROP PROCEDURE dbo.RecordActivityRun");

        }
    }
}
```

The issue when I come to run my release pipeline on Azure Dev Ops, I get the following error:

> ##[error]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
>  Must declare the scalar variable "@activityName"

I thought that the issue might be in how the variables are being declared? But it seems like that's standard declaration for SP's? When I run it on my localhost db, using Update-Database, I don't get any errors.

Comment: See [this article](https://dotnetthoughts.net/creating-stored-procs-in-efcore-migrations/). The likely issue is that a stored procedure definition cannot be defined within conditonals or alongside other stored procedure definitions within the same "batch". (In SSMS scripts, `GO` statements are used as batch separators.) Depending on how the migration is executed, you might be able to just insert `GO` statements. Alternately, you can use an `EXEC()` to apply a quoted definition of the stored procedure - `migrationBuilder.Sql(@"EXEC('CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.RecordActivity (...) AS INSERT ...')");`.